# Salesforce Community - Contact support web-to-case error message

Tags: community

Greetings and thanks for the read!

Have a sites community template where I wish to prevent users from contacting support ( i.e. creating a case)

For authenticated community users they receive the correct error message ( user does not have access to create a case - this is correct )

For unauthenticated users they receive the following message ( web-toCase must be enabled and configured )

If one turns on web-to-Case then the unauthenticated user can complete the case submission form but it appears that it doesn't create the case ( incorrect behavior.  )  This user does not have system permission to create cases.  Turning off web-to-case gets me back to this cryptic message.

Has anyone seen this or know how to get a proper error message.. This feels like a sf.com bug.

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why not simply remove the Contact Support button from the template? I realise this doesn't answer the question of why the error message is incorrect, but it would seem pointless to show a button if you're never going to let your users use it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  The button needs to be available for other profiles which can and do create cases.  Consider using visualforce to render based on profile but cannot seem to find this component / page.

Answer (score 0):

Page variations allow you to precisely address this kind of use case, where you have a page variation for authenticated users and anotherone for guest users where there is no button.

> **Page Variations and Audience Targeting for Pages and Groups**
>
> Criteria-based page visibility lets you create different versions of
>   your page and make those variations available to specific audiences
>   and groups.

Official [DOCUMENTATION](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5)